# Using Otto for bidirectional communication with a dialog

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to pass an event from a fragment to a dialog using otto. Unfortunately by the time the dialog is created the event has already fired and the @Subscribe method in my dialog and the data that was being sent gets passed over.

The data I'm trying to pass is an Object and an index (Best case) or a String (worst case) from a listview/ArrayList.

I know they have an @Produce method; but I don't understand how a method that takes no arguments helps in anyway or how I can get it to work.

Here's an example they provide

```
@Produce public AnswerAvailableEvent produceAnswer() {
    // Assuming 'lastAnswer' exists.
    return new AnswerAvailableEvent(this.lastAnswer);
}
```

For my newly created dialog this.lastAnswer; won't exist, it can't - that's what I'm passing in.So how do I get around this?

Side note: 
I think the event bus, in it's current form is a bit of overkill since it's only communicating with my dialog. Later on I hope to use the event bus in more dialogfrag/fragment communication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also asked same question for myself, when I was investigating Otto. And decided to read their site(http://square.github.io/otto/) more thoughtfully.
Here is their description under @Produce annotation:

> ...
>   Producers, like subscribers, must also be registered...
>   When registering, the producer method will be
>   called once for each subscriber previously registered for the same
>   type. The producer method will also be called once for each new method
>   that subscribes to an event of the same type.
>
> You may only have one producer per event type registered at a time on
>   a bus.

So I think in time you register your producer, "lastAnswer" should be initialized.
And no parameters needed because you don't suppose to call your producer-method by yourself.
I hope it will help.

Comment: lastAnswer won't ever be initialized in my scenario. I'm passing data from my fragment to a dialog so there is no (last time). Good thoughts though! I'll keep it in mind for next time I dive into android.

Comment: Sorry @xphill64x , maybe I not quiet understand, if you don't need to pass to dialog "lastTime", create Event without passing it in constructor.